# Modify C-array in objective-c function

Tags: ios, c, arrays, pointers, parameters

As an iOS programmer I sometimes delve into C to achieve faster results (well actually for fun) and I'm struggling to modify a C-array's values inside a function call. Although I think this answer may help ([Modifying a array in a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568414/modifying-a-array-in-a-function-in-c)), I don't know where to begin in implementing it.

Currently I have:

```
[object.guestlists enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {

   NSObject *someNSObject = [NSObject new];

   NSInteger array[3] = {totalIncomingMales,totalIncomingFemales, 
                        totalIncomingGuestsCount};

   [self callMethod:object withCArray:cArray];

}];


- (void) callMethod:(NSObject*) object withCArray:(NSInteger*) cArray {

    // do something with that object

    NSInteger   totalIncomingMales = cArray[0],
                totalIncomingFemales = cArray[1],
                totalIncomingGuestsCount = cArray[2];

    // modify these integers internally so that the C-array passed in is also modified

}
```

Obviously this passes a pointer and therefore doesn't modify the value. I tried replacing the NSinteger * with NSInteger ** and making, 
e.g. **totalIncomingMales = * cArray[0]**, but alas I wasn't able to pass the c-array as a parameter (even with an ampersand).

Some useful material and potentially a solution to this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You use ** only with NSObjects and its subclass. NSInteger is just a primitive int. I believe * and/ & should work.

Comment: Where does `arrayOfIntegers` come from?

Comment: Sorry, have edited. I tried using ampersand, I think. Let me try again

Comment: Yer, just using the ampersand gives me a compiler warning NSInteger(*)[3] to NSInteger * (aka int *)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but it seems to be trivial one:

```
- (void) callMethod:(NSObject*) object withCArray:(NSInteger*) cArray {
     // modify these integers internally so that the C-array passed in is also modified
     cArray[0] = 10;
     cArray[1] = 20;
     cArray[2] = 30;
}


- (void) myMethod:(NSString *) myConstString array: (NSArray *) myArray
{
    NSInteger array[3] = {1,2,3};
    NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld", (long)array[0],(long)array[1],(long)array[2]);
    [self callMethod:nil withCArray:array];
    NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld", (long)array[0],(long)array[1],(long)array[2]);
}
```

result will be:
1,2,3
after 10,20,30. No pointer trickery needed, because you are telling it is NSInteger so compiler does it for you.

Comment: That's it. It was a slip on my part and I shouldn't have been assigning them to new variables. So dum.